# Resolving DNS subdomains

Tags: dns

I'm not sure I understand DNS correctly. Given a computer which has the domain name `somecomputer.com`, and I setup a DNS server on that computer, will requests for `subdomain.somecomputer.com` go through that DNS server?

Comment: 1. Only if you create a zone in the DNS server for `somedomain.com` AND 2. Only for the clients that query that DNS server for `somedomain.com`.

Comment: Will this happen automatically if `subdomain.somecomputer.com` cannot be resolved from other dns servers?

Comment: No it won't. DNS clients need to know to ask your server. That isn't automatic. For a public DNS zone you need to register your DNS server(s) with your domain name registrar. For a private domain you need to configure your clients to use your DNS server for DNS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say "has the domain name", I'm guessing you meant "the `example.com` A/AAAA records point to the computer's IP address". If that's the case, the answer is no – it has absolutely no effect on how the subdomains of `example.com` are resolved.

Rather, DNS has a different record type – the NS record – that delegates a sub-domain to another DNS server. For example, the `com` domain has `example.com` NS pointing at your registrar's (or your own) DNS servers.

Regarding your "Will this happen automatically" comment: Unlike some other protocols (e.g. SMTP with its MX records and fallback to A/AAAA), the domain name system itself is quite strict about this. When you query a DNS server about any name, it can either return the data directly; or point you elsewhere by returning NS records; or admit that it doesn't know that name. There are no other options.